# Convert two polynomials into a target polynomials through operations

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> You are provided with two polynomials $x^3-3x^2+2$ and $x^2-4x$ on a
> piece of paper.
>
> If there are polynomials $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ on the paper, you are allowed
> to write $f(x) + g(x)$, $f(x) - g(x)$, $f(x)g(x)$, $f(g(x))$ and
> $cf(x)$.
>
> Can you obtain a linear polynomial (exactly one degree) given
> two starting polynomials?

I feel like this could be a linear algebra problem, if the operations are just $f(x) + g(x)$, $f(x) - g(x)$ and $cf(x)$ Then we are looking for the linear dependence. But now sure how to handle $f(x)g(x)$, $f(g(x))$

Comment: $f(x) - f(x)$ is linear lol.

Comment: @SenZen sorry i think the problem meant to ask for exaclty 1 degree..

Comment: I think it's possible so long as $f \neq g$

Comment: Actually never mind i have no idea.

Comment: It's possible if you also allow $f(cx)$ as a valid operation.

Comment: @SenZen would be interested to learn about the solution involving $f(cx)$

Comment: @Vendetta I should mention it doesn't always work, such as when the given polynomials have no $x$ terms to begin with. But if one of them does, the basic idea is this:

Comment: I'll use the example of $g(x) = x^3 - x^2 + 2x + 3$. First compute $g(2x) = 8x^3 - 4x^2 + 4x + 3$, and $8g(x) = 8x^3 - 8x^2 + 16x + 24$. Now subtract those, $g(2x) - 8g(x) = 4x^2 - 12x + 27$. Observe we've reduced the degree from 3 to 2, and by repeating this process we can get it down to one.

Comment: @GerogeKlein Which contest was this from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, subtraction decreases the degree if the leading coefficients are the same (which we can ensure with $cf(x)$), so all we need is polynomials of the same degree. This is the crux. See if you can work it out before reading on.

---

We currently do not have 2 polynomials of the same degree, so let's force them out and take their difference. I will work with the specific cases of $a(x) = x^3 - 3x^2 + 2$, $b(x) = x^2 - 4x$, but I suspect this will generalize (with certain conditions).

Step 1: Calculate $a(x)a(x) = x^6 - 6x^5 + 9x^4 + 4x^3 - 12x^2 + 4$.
Step 2: Calculate $b(x)b(x)b(x) = x^6 - 12x^4 + 48x^2 - 64  $. This gives us 2 polynomials of degree 6.
Step 3: Take their difference $a(x)^2 - b(x)^3 = 6x^5 -39 x^4 + 68x^3 - 12x^2 + 4 = c(x) $.
Step 4: Calculate $a(x) b(x) = x^5 - 7x^4 + 12x^3 + 2x^2 - 8x $. This gives us 2 polynomials of degree 5.
Step 5: Take their difference $ c(x) - 6a(x) b(x) = -15x^4 + 86x^3 - 96x^2 + 48x + 4 = d(x)$.
Step 6: Calculate $b(x) b(x)  = x^4 - 8x^3 + 16x^2$. This gives us 2 polynomials of degree 4.
Step 7: Take their difference $d(x) + 15 6 b(x)b(x) = -34x^3 + 144x^2 + 48x + 4 = e(x) $, which is a polynomial of degree 3.
Step 8: Take their difference $ e(x) + 34 a(x) = 42x^2 + 48x + 72 = f(x) $, which is a polynomial of degree (at most, and hopefully) 2.
Step 9: Take their difference $ f(x)  - 42 b(x) = 216x+72 $, which is a polynomial of degree 1.

---

Notes

- As SenZen mentions, if our initial polynomials don't have a linear term, then none of the operations would have led to a linear term. So this isn't always doable.
- As implied by SenZen, we might lower the degree by more than one if the ratio of the first few coefficients are equal. This has happened when I was using $ a(b(x)) , b(a(x))$ as my starting polynomials, and I didn't end up with a polynomial of degree 1.
- This process is not unique. We could have made different choices for the polynomials of higher degrees.
- I might have a calculation error. If so, let me know. This was way to much calculation for a contest-math problem, even after knowing the crux, so I'd like to know of an alternative solution.

Comment: Nice answer but I think you've understated the possible things that can go wrong. For instance, if we start with any 2 polynomials with _no_ $x$ term, then no operation can possibly yield another with an $x$ term. As such, the $x$ term is un-reachable and though we might be able to reduce to a quadratic, after that it will skip linears and go straight to constant!

Comment: But this problem can also happen along the way. What if in one of the sutractions, the $x$ terms cancel? Then from that point onwards they are gone forever! And this scenario has nothing to do with the roots because a polynomial's roots habe nothing to do with it's $x$ term.

Comment: @SenZen Ah, I see what you mean. In fact, as it turns out, I do skip to (non-zero) constant directly.

Comment: @SenZen Alright, fixed it for this particular case. I would not be surprised if the polynomial in the contest was $ x^2 - 4$ instead, as this was way too much work for the payoff.